# how to convert a string type to a task type

Tags: c#, wpf, task

I have a string of `xml` node which consists of certain tasks, and a string of project list, I'm iterating through both tasks and project list, and calling a function of another class and passing the tasks and projectlist, but it's giving me an error of `best overloaded method and it has some invalid argument`. I am assuming that it is a type conversion error.

Here is my code:

```
private void addtask(object sender,RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (object item in tasklistBox.Items)
        {
            var listBoxItem = tasklistBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item);
            var myContentPresenter = FindVisualChild<ContentPresenter>(listBoxItem);
            var myDataTemplate = myContentPresenter.ContentTemplate;
            var mydata = (System.Windows.Controls.Label)myDataTemplate.FindName("tasklabel", myContentPresenter);
            var xmlElement = (XmlElement)mydata.Content;
            //System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(xmlElement.InnerText);

            foreach (Harvest_Project item1 in Globals._globalController.harvestManager._PROJECTLIST)
            {
                Globals._globalController.harvestManager.assignTaskToProject(xmlElement.InnerText,item1);
            }
        }
    }
```

and the function of another class which i am calling:

```
public void assignTaskToProject(Harvest_Task task, Harvest_Project project)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Assigning Task to Project");

        string assignXML = "<task>" +
                                "<id type=\"integer\">" + task._id + "</id>  " +
                           "</task>";

        sendPOSTRequest(uri + _GETALLPROJECTS + "/" + project._id + "/task_assignments", assignXML);

    }
```

the `Harvest_Task` class is here:

```
private bool _billable_by_default;

    private bool _deactivated;

    private float _default_hourly_rate=0;

    public int _id { get; set; }

    private bool _is_default;

    public string _name { get; set; }

    private DateTime _created_at;

    private DateTime _updated_at;

    private XmlNode _node;

    public Harvest_Task()
    { }

    public Harvest_Task(XmlNode node)
    {

        this._node = node;
        this._name = node.SelectSingleNode("name").InnerText;


        this._created_at = Harvest_Base.storeTime(node.SelectSingleNode("created-at").InnerText);
        this._updated_at = Harvest_Base.storeTime(node.SelectSingleNode("updated-at").InnerText);

        this._is_default = bool.Parse(node.SelectSingleNode("is-default").InnerText);
        this._deactivated = bool.Parse(node.SelectSingleNode("deactivated").InnerText);

        float.TryParse(node.SelectSingleNode("default-hourly-rate").InnerText,out this._default_hourly_rate);
        this._id = int.Parse(node.SelectSingleNode("id").InnerText);


    }

    public Harvest_Task(string name, float defaultHourlyRate)
    {
        this._name = name;
        this._default_hourly_rate = defaultHourlyRate;
    }

    public string createXMLAddEntry()
    {
        string returnXML = "<task>" +
                                "<billable-by-default type=\"boolean\">true</billable-by-default>" +
                                "<default-hourly-rate type=\"decimal\">"+this._default_hourly_rate+"</default-hourly-rate>" +
                                "<is-default type=\"boolean\">true</is-default>" +
                                "<name>" + this._name + "</name>  " +
                           "</task>";


        return returnXML;
    }
```

the `Harvest_Project` class is here

```
    public string _name { get; set; }

    private DateTime _over_budget_notified_at;

    private bool _billable;

    private DateTime _created_at;

    private bool _active;

    private enum _bill_by { Tasks, People, none };

    public int _client_id = 0;

    private string _code;

    private string _notes;

    private enum _budget_by { project, project_cost, task, person, none };

    private float _budget = 0; //Budget in hrs

    private DateTime _latest_record_at;

    private DateTime _earliest_record_at;

    private int _fees = 0;

    public int _id { get; set; }

    private DateTime _updated_at;

    private XmlNode _node;

    public int getId() { return this._id; }

    public Harvest_Project(XmlNode node)
    {
        this._node = node;
        this._name = node.SelectSingleNode("name").InnerText;

        this._created_at = storeTime(node.SelectSingleNode("created-at").InnerText);
        this._updated_at = storeTime(node.SelectSingleNode("updated-at").InnerText);
        this._over_budget_notified_at = storeTime(node.SelectSingleNode("over-budget-notified-at").InnerText);
        this._latest_record_at = storeTime(node.SelectSingleNode("hint-latest-record-at").InnerText);
        this._earliest_record_at = storeTime(node.SelectSingleNode("hint-earliest-record-at").InnerText);

        this._billable = bool.Parse(node.SelectSingleNode("billable").InnerText);

        try
        {
            this._id = Convert.ToInt32(getXmlNode("id", node));
            this._client_id = Convert.ToInt32(getXmlNode("client-id", node));
            this._budget = float.Parse(getXmlNode("budget", node));
            this._fees = Convert.ToInt32(getXmlNode("fees", node));

        }
        catch (OverflowException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The number cannot fit in an Int32.");
        }
        catch (FormatException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The string is not a valid integer");
        }

        this._code = node.SelectSingleNode("code").InnerText;
        this._notes = node.SelectSingleNode("notes").InnerText;


    }
```

this function has `Harvest_task` and `Harvest_Project` classes, I am calling this function but unable to call. This line giving an error

`Globals._globalController.harvestManager.assignTaskToProject(xmlElement.InnerText,item1);`
What conversion to use? I am stuck

Any help? thanks

Comment: can you share your xml for xmlElement and the Harvest_Task class?

Comment: @pushpraj yes,i will share the class and xml file image

Comment: your xml seems missing the `id` which is required in `assignTaskToProject` method. is it the right xml? Also I find it little confusing the way you are retrieving the xmlElement, is it correct for you?

Comment: thats fine no tweaks in that,i just need to pass the task and project value to the function.

Comment: the xml is from where i tooked my task

Comment: OK, now I am concerned about the `task._id` which is needed to prepare `assignXML`. where this value is supposed to come from?

Comment: and id is assigned in the class ,which is generated over there,no issue in that,how can i pass the task and project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far from what I can see you can use this

```
foreach (Harvest_Project item1 in Globals._globalController.harvestManager._PROJECTLIST)
{
    Globals._globalController.harvestManager.assignTaskToProject(new Harvest_Task(xmlElement), item1);
}
```

I am using the constructor `public Harvest_Task(XmlNode node)` from the Harvest_Task to create an instance instead of `xmlElement.InnerText` to be passed as parameter to `assignTaskToProject` method

I suspect it to fail too as your xml does not have any id and constructor expect `node.SelectSingleNode("id").InnerText`

Answer (score 0):

You will somehow need to parse the InnerText property to create the type of Harvest_Task - InnerText will be of type string, so it might be a plan to add a 'Converter' class which takes in the string type and outputs a Harvest_Task object.

```
class HarvestTaskConverter {
    public Harvest_Task Convert(string text) {
        var task = new Harvest_Task();
        // parse the text here
        return task;
    }
}
```

Just a couple of additional comments - the method/ variable naming is not very C# - camelCase is preferred, and 'global' variables are generally frowned upon, but it all depends on whether you have control over the other code.